# Cannot load a plain text file generated by a PHP - script using curl utility

Tags: unix, curl, command-line, plaintext

I am sitting on a Mac OS X system and I cannot get around a simple problem from the domain of working with the command line: using the command `curl http://mureakuha.com/dl.php?type=1&id=1234` I get no data from a (obviously) PHP script generating plain text files.

I expect the solution to be a matter of passing right flags to **curl**, yet I have no clue where to start. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `curl 'http://mureakuha.com/dl.php?type=1&id=1234'`. The problem here is the unquoted `&` symbol in url.